# FileSystemException when runnning a Dart Shelf Docker Container

Tags: flutter, docker, api, dart-shelf

I generated a dart project with `dart create -t server-shelf . --force`.

On the top folder I created a json file (my_data.json) with some mock data.
In my code I am using the data from the json file like:

```
final _data = json.decode(File('my_data.json').readAsStringSync()) as List<dynamic>;
```

But if I try to start my server with `docker run -it -p 8080:8080 myserver` I am getting:

> FileSystemException: Cannot open file, path = 'my_data.json' (OS
> Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

My Dockerfile:

```
# Use latest stable channel SDK.
FROM dart:stable AS build

# Resolve app dependencies.
WORKDIR /app
COPY pubspec.* ./
RUN dart pub get

# Copy app source code (except anything in .dockerignore) and AOT compile app.
COPY . .
RUN dart compile exe bin/server.dart -o bin/server

# Build minimal serving image from AOT-compiled `/server`
# and the pre-built AOT-runtime in the `/runtime/` directory of the base image.
FROM scratch
COPY --from=build /runtime/ /
COPY --from=build /app/bin/server /app/bin/
COPY my_data.json /app/my_data.json

# Start server.
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/app/bin/server"]
```

Comment: I suspect you have the wrong current directory for the app.  Either open `/app/my_data.json` in your program, or figure out how to cd to the right directory before launching the app.  Hint: running an app doesn't change the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you didn't set the `WORKDIR` for the new image that you started building `FROM scratch`. You can fix this simply by adding `WORKDIR /app` again, to the specification of the new image you're building, which is being used to run your application. It will look like this:

```
...

# Start server.
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/app/bin/server"]
```

Comment: did not work :(

Comment: what if you use the path `/app/my_data.json` in your application. Does that work?

Comment: I tried:
COPY --from=build /app/my_data.json my_data.json

but it does not work. Still the same exception.

Comment: No, I mean in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
COPY my_data.json /app/my_data.json
```

with

```
COPY --from=build app/my_data.json app/
```